# Prisma findmany() gives me a server error?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, error-handling, next.js, prisma

I was testing my new implemented prisma/postgresql database, but while searching for specific keywords, I got this error :

"Error:
Invalid `prisma.easytokens.findMany()` invocation:

Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42601), message: "syntax error in tsquery: "Luna Rush"", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("tsquery.c"), line: Some(692), routine: Some("makepol") }) }) })"

I have checked if the database is correctly connected to prisma & if the prisma client is intsalled, but all good.

Any suggestions?

Models :

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fullTextSearch"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Token {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement()) 
  tokenName String @db.VarChar(255)
  whitelistWallets String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  tokenAddress String @db.VarChar(255)
  coingecko String @db.VarChar(255)
  month String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m1 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m2 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m3 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m4 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m5 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m6 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m7 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m8 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m9 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m10 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m11 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m12 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m13 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m14 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m15 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  tge String[] @db.VarChar(255)
}

model easytokens {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement()) 
  tokenName String @db.VarChar(255)
  whitelistWallets String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  tokenAddress String @db.VarChar(255)
  coingecko String @db.VarChar(255)
  month String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m1 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m2 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m3 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m4 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m5 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m6 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m7 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m8 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m9 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m10 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m11 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m12 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m13 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m14 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  m15 String[] @db.VarChar(255)
  tge String[] @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

Search function :

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import Head from 'next/head'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Prismafilter from './prismafilter';

const prisma = new PrismaClient()


export default function Kek(props) {

    const {data} = props.result;

    console.log(data)

}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const result = await prisma.easytokens.findMany({
        where: {
          tokenName: {
            search: 'Luna Rush',
          },
        },
      })

    return {
      props: {
        
        result,
    
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
```